# Lazy loading routing propagationsin angular

Tags: angular, routes, angular-routing

I have this router configuration in module user.

The routes start with `/users`

```
{path: '', component: UsersComponent},


{
    path: 'manage/roles',
    component: ManageRoleComponent,
    canActivate: [MyGuard],
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: ':id',
    component: ViewUserComponent,
    canActivate: [MyGuard],
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
```

If I navigate to `/users/12` by calling `await this.router.navigate(['/users', event.value.uid]);` and then navigate `/users/manage/role`s by routerLink,  the router has `/users/12` is beign called automatically. So the `viewUserComponent.ts` is excuted

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please explain in more details what action you did and what went wrong? Right now its bit unclear.

Comment: Two components are called at the same time mange.role.component.ts and view.users.ts component when I click manage-role component

Comment: Is it possible to share a stackblitz, and also mention angular version you're using?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.

Routing was not the problem.The issue was in the view.user.component I had a subscription. So when I navigate away from this component
Angular still call the subscription.

So i changed subscription to

```
firstValueFrom(this.store.select(data)).then(result => {
 }).catch(reason => {
      console.log()
 });
```

Instead of

```
this.userSubscription = this.store.select(data).subscribe(result => { });
```